# Can't complete this trailhead module(Create a Candidate Rating Flow)

Tags: lightning-flow-builder

I am not able to find two of the fields. I have followed all the steps correctly still I am facing this issue. I have attached all the screenshot required. Please let me know my mistake

Trailhead URL : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/automate-business-processes-recruiting-app/candidate-rating-flow

Getting error in SET A START ELEMENT

[image]

[image: The experience comments and leadership skills comments are not being added]

[image: Those fields are not available to select also]

[image: I have created those fields in the previous step as it was asked]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE!  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  
The best resource for Challenge questions is [Trailhead Help](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help) where there is a community focused on Challenges, and you an also open a case with Salesforce for technical issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the label for the element as 'createReview' itself?

Also in the attached screenshot , mapping for experience_comments__c and leadership_skills_comments__c are missing.

Comment: Yes I have given the label as 'createReview' and to answer the second part of your question - That is what I am not getting. I am not able to find those fields over there while mapping